# Why isn't my javafx combobox button cell renderer being applied until a selection is made?

Tags: combobox, cell, javafx, renderer

I'm extending ComboBox and attempting to customize the button graphic such that it displays a checked/unchecked status depending on whether an item in the list has been selected. No value is selected by default, so it simply shows the prompt text, and I *want* it to display the "unchecked" graphic, but I can't seem to get a graphic of any sort to appear until the user has selected a value, which kind of defeats the purpose of having a graphic...

```
public class ComponentComboBox extends ComboBox<String> {

    String promptText;
    boolean promptAsPrefix = true; // keeps the prompt as a prefix to the selected item
    final ImageView checked = new ImageView( new Image( Main.actions.getClass().getResourceAsStream( "res/checked.png" ) ) );
    final ImageView unchecked = new ImageView( new Image( Main.actions.getClass().getResourceAsStream( "res/unchecked.png" ) ) );

    public ComponentComboBox( String promptText, boolean promptAsPrefix, int maxWidth ) {
        init( promptText, promptAsPrefix, maxWidth );
    }

    private void init( final String promptText, final boolean promptAsPrefix, int maxWidth ) {
        this.promptText = promptText;
        this.promptAsPrefix = promptAsPrefix;
        setPromptText( promptText );
        setMaxWidth( maxWidth );
        setPrefWidth( maxWidth );
        Callback<ListView<String>,ListCell<String>> cb = new Callback<ListView<String>,ListCell<String>>() {
            @Override public ListCell<String> call( ListView<String> p ) {
                ListCell<String> ret = new ListCell<String>() {
                    @Override protected void updateItem( String item, boolean empty ) {
                        super.updateItem( item, empty );
                        if ( item == null || empty ) {
                            setGraphic( unchecked );
                        } 
                        else {
                            setGraphic( checked );
                            if ( promptAsPrefix ) {
                                setText( promptText + " " + item );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                ret.setGraphic( unchecked );
                return ret;
            }
        };
        setButtonCell( cb.call( null ) );
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to have a custom graphic displayed when no value has been selected?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
setButtonCell( cb.call( null ) );
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getButtonCell().updateIndex(0);
        }
    });
```